# Forcing a browser to open a webpage using either HTTP or HTTPS by bypassing the cache

Tags: javascript, http, browser, https

I have my Nginx web server running on both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. If the application tries to open:

```
https://myapp.com/path1
```

it opens the application with `HTTPS` but when it attempts to open using:

```
http://myapp.com/path1
```

the browser uses its cache and opens with `https`. How could I prevent this? I have a button to open specific webpages. When someone clicks on the button, I create the URL and then call:

```
window.open(previewURL, "_blank");
```

Is there a way where I can force the browser to open using `http` when I want in `http` and `https` when I want in `https`?

If I open the webpage in a private window (incognito), the browser then won't redirect.

Comment: so your nginx isn't set to redirect http to https?

Comment: @JaromandaX No. This is intentional. A preview could either be opened with `http` or `https`.

Comment: Is there a way to supply the rest of the code leading up to window.open? (or perhaps a link to the server, or a test/temp version of it, for us to test it?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/2016831

Comment: @bluejayke Even after doing the cache thing, the browser still redirects to https. When I clear the cache, it works fine the very first time. But if I refresh, it redirects to https